# Header and Footer offset in Exam Document Class

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, exam

I am using the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam)  document class and I want to implement a layout where the headers and footers span over both the text body and the margins.

I tried using the `\fancyhfoffset` command from the `fancyhdr` package, but commands like `\cfoot`, `\lfoot` are overruled by the document class.

Is there a way to disable the native header and footers from the `exam` document class or some other way of implementing this?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[includemp, a4paper, textwidth=0.6\paperwidth, marginparwidth=0.2\paperwidth]{geometry}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpagefooter{MyName}{MyTitle}{ThePage}
\runningfooter{MyName}{MyTitle}{ThePage}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyName}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you would like to achieve? ASAIK, the `exam` class provides commands for such things.

Comment: @karlkoeller Like so?

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue or you were looking for something else?

Comment: I am looking for a way to make the header and footer broader, including both text area and margins within.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to achieve.

Anyway the commands to move headers and footers up and and down in your document when using the `exam` class are, respectively, `\extraheadheight` and `\extrafootheight`.

They have to be used in the preamble and their sintax is

```
\extraheadheight[<1st page spacing>]{<spacing>}
```

and

```
\extrafootheight[<1st page spacing>]{<spacing>}
```

If the optional argument is omitted, then all pages including the first are affected by these commands.

Give positive values if you want headers/footers closer to the text, negative values if you want headers/footers closer to the margins of the page.

The following is an example that shows you how they act when you give different values for the first and the running pages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[includemp, a4paper, textwidth=0.6\paperwidth, marginparwidth=0.2\paperwidth]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpagefooter{MyName}{MyTitle}{ThePage}
\runningfooter{MyName}{MyTitle}{ThePage}
\firstpageheader{MyName}{MyTitle}{ThePage}
\runningheader{MyName}{MyTitle}{ThePage}

\extraheadheight[.25in]{.5in}
\extrafootheight[.25in]{.5in}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyName}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]